# Change imageView with time of day

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview

I'm trying to have imageView updated based on time of day but for some reason its not working and not getting any compilation error.

Code:

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int timeOfDay = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if (timeOfDay >=20 && timeOfDay <=4) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.night);
            }else if (timeOfDay >= 5 && timeOfDay <= 8) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunset);

            } else if (timeOfDay >= 9 && timeOfDay <= 16) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.morning);

            }
            else if (timeOfDay >= 17 && timeOfDay <= 19) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunset);
            }
        }
```

Activity.xml code:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="606dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `if (timeOfDay >=20 && timeOfDay <=4)` condition is not executed(false). Becuse there are no time whcih is >=20 and <=4

according to your condition, you need these two conditions as well

```
   if (timeOfDay >=0 && timeOfDay <=4)
```

and

```
   else if (timeOfDay >=20 && timeOfDay <=24)
```

add these two and related images for it and remove not executing that above mentioned condition

you can smiply do it like below

```
   if (timeOfDay >= 5 && timeOfDay <= 8) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunset);

        } else if (timeOfDay >= 9 && timeOfDay <= 16) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.morning);

        }
        else if (timeOfDay >= 17 && timeOfDay <= 19) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunset);
        }
        else{
             //exectue this for 0-4 and 20-24
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.night);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works only from 5 to 19, because `(timeOfDay >=20 && timeOfDay <=4)` returns always false.

Answer (score 0):

> (timeOfDay >=20 && timeOfDay <=4)

The condition is not reachable. Because there is no time which >=20 and <=4. In this case, because timeOfDay always > 0 so change your code to

> (timeOfDay >=20 || timeOfDay <=4)

And do not forget to reformat your code.